# TWIG: variable is defined in a long list

Tags: symfony, twig

I am building a page with Twig displaying User data; Data is from the a User and Profile Entities (that you can access from User).

To avoid the page displaying an error when a variable is null I have to check if each variable is defined (which makes the code much heavier as you can see).

```
        <dt>firstname:</dt>
            {% if user.firstname is defined %}
                <dd>{{ user.firstname|title }}</dd>
            {% endif %}
        <dt>lastname:</dt>
            {% if user.lastname is defined %}
                <dd>{{ user.lastname|title }}</dd>
            {% endif %}
        <dt>Email address:</dt>
            {% if user.lastname is defined %}
                <dd>{{ user.email|title }}</dd>
            {% endif %}
        <dt>Birthday:</dt>
            {% if user.profile.birthday is defined %}
                <dd>{{ user.profile.birthday|date("d M y") }}</dd>  
            {% endif %}
        <dt>Mobile phone:</dt>
            {% if user.profile.mobilePhone is defined %}                
                <dd>{{ user.profile.mobilePhone }}</dd>
            {% endif %}
        <dt>Landline:</dt>
            {% if user.profile.landline is defined %}                
                <dd>{{ user.profile.landline }}</dd>
            {% endif %}  
        <dt>Website:</dt>
            {% if user.profile.website is defined %}                
                <dd>{{ user.profile.website }}</dd>
            {% endif %}
```

Is there a way to avoid doing that? A nicer and shorter way to check if variable are defined before displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: no, there are no shortcuts AFAIK, except using a ternary operator:

```
{{ user.profile.landline is defined ? user.profile.landline : "" }}
```

or even the shorter syntax

```
{{ user.profile.landline is defined ? user.profile.landline }}
```

But I'd say that these checks should be made in the controller instead, so that variables in Twig are always defined. The less conditional you have in a Twig template, the better.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this shorter syntax ;) Neat :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this could fit your needs but you could do:

```
<dd>{{ user.profile.landline|default("") }}</dd>
```

As for the filtered data, the approach is similar:

```
<dd>{{ user.firstname|default("")|title }}</dd>
```

Now, the problem would the the date. I assume, you don't want to default it to `today` or any other for that matter.

**@Francesco** also posted quite simple solution, so it might be better depending on what you're really trying to achieve (e.g. printing `<dd>` only if data is defined, date attribute, etc...).

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the best answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your configuration for twig:

> If a variable or attribute does not exist, you will receive a null value when the strict_variables option is set to false; alternatively, if strict_variables is set, Twig will throw an error (see environment options).
>   [Source](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables)

Add the following line in the correct section of your config.yml:

```
twig:
     strict_variables: false
```

[Here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) you got some more info.

*Edit:* 
As @Jovan Perovic in the comment-section already mentioned, this solution is a bit **risky**. After setting `strict_variables: false` Twig won't throw any exceptions regarding your used variables, even if you made a simple typo in the variables name. This can make your code validation much more complex.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly @JovanPerovic?

Comment: disabling strict variable checking (app-wide) would leave you wide open to errors (variables' typos). In turn, you would need to invest much more time in testing you application in order to confirm correctness of functionality. Suddenly, you find yourself unsure if you data is actually empty, or you've just mistyped the name, right?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Thanks. This is of course somewhat risky and therefore maybe not the best solution. Will add this doubts in my answer-post. Cheers.

Comment: Just explain a bit more why is risky to do use `strict_variables`, but this is a good answer. Consider adding @JovanPerovic comments.